# Can't get Flagging API to accept POST request

Tags: 8, flags

trying to use the REST API that comes with the flagging module on Drupal 8.

I've enabled and secured the endpoint that comes with the module: /entity/flagging: POST

I'm nearly there, but following examples from earlier releases don't seem to work; What I'm trying to achieve is adding a flag for one user (1) for one content item (34). I got this far on the POST:

```
{
"entity_id":[{"target_id":34}],
"flag_id": "my_flag",
"uid": [{"target_id": 1 }],
"flag_action": "flag"
}
```

But I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Field flag_action is unknown.
```

Without the flag_action argument though I get:

```
{"message":"You are not authorized to create this flagging entity of bundle my flag."}
```

I'm not sure how I can not be authorised i'm sending credentials of the sys admin (using basic_auth).

Anybody know how I can add or remove a single flag from an entity using the Rest API?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to create a flag, however, I had the same results.

To solve this, I have created a module.

***note: to make tests I installed the "Flag Bookmark" module.***
file test_api.info.yml.

```
    name: Test API
    type: module
    description: Custom RESTful API module with GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc.. method examples.
    author: Minnur Yunusov
    core: 8.x
```

file test_api.routing.yml.

```
# Test API endpoints

  test_api.get:
  path: 'my-api/get.json'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController::get_example' }
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

test_api.put:
  path: 'my-api/put.json'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController::put_example' }
  methods:  [PUT]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

test_api.post:
  path: 'my-api/post.json'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController::post_example' }
  methods:  [POST]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

test_api.delete:
  path: 'my-api/delete.json'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController::delete_example' }
  methods:  [DELETE]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

we create the following directories and file TestAPIController.php
src/Controller/TestAPIController.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController.
 */

namespace Drupal\test_api\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Controller routines for test_api routes.
 */
class TestAPIController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Callback for `my-api/get.json` API method.
   */
  public function get_example( Request $request ) {

    $response['data'] = 'Some test data to return';
    $response['method'] = 'GET';

    return new JsonResponse( $response );
  }

  /**
   * Callback for `my-api/put.json` API method.
   */
  public function put_example( Request $request ) {

    $response['data'] = 'Some test data to return';
    $response['method'] = 'PUT';

    return new JsonResponse( $response );
  }

  /**
   * Callback for `my-api/post.json` API method.
   */
  public function post_example( Request $request ) {

    // This condition checks the `Content-type` and makes sure to 
    // decode JSON string from the request body into array.
    if ( 0 === strpos( $request->headers->get( 'Content-Type' ), 'application/json' ) ) {
      $data = json_decode( $request->getContent(), TRUE );
      $request->request->replace( is_array( $data ) ? $data : [] );
    }


    //get value json
    $flag_id= $data["flag_id"];
    $entity_type= $data["entity_type"];
    $entity_id = $data["entity_id"];
    $uid= $data["uid"];
    $created = REQUEST_TIME;

    //get user   
    $user= User::load($uid);

    //get field uuid
    $user_uuid= $user->get('uuid')->value;

    //add entity_id to the field field uuid (unique value);
    $user_uuid= $user_uuid.'-'.$data["entity_id"];

    $fields=array(
      'flag_id' => $flag_id,
      'uuid' =>$user_uuid, //unique value
      'entity_type' =>$entity_type,
      'entity_id' => $entity_id,
      'uid' =>$uid,
      'global' =>0,
      'created' => $created
    );


    if ($data["flag_action"]=='flag') {

        //verify if exists record
        $sql="select * from {flagging} where entity_type ='$entity_type' and entity_id=$entity_id and flag_id='$flag_id' and uid=$uid ";    
        //execute query
        $connection = \Drupal::database();
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        $result=$result->fetchAll();

        //if not exists record, create flag
        if (count($result)>0) {
          $response['¿Flag exists?'] = 'true';
        }
        else {


              $resultado= db_insert('flagging')
              ->fields($fields)
              ->execute();  

              $response['newflag'] = $resultado;

        }


        $response['data'] = $data;


    }


    else if ($data["flag_action"]=='unflag') {

        //verify if exits record
        $sql="select * from {flagging} where entity_type ='$entity_type' and entity_id=$entity_id and flag_id='$flag_id' and uid=$uid ";    
        //execute query
        $connection = \Drupal::database();
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
        $result=$result->fetchAll();

        //if exists record, delete flag
        if (count($result)>0) {

          $num_deleted = db_delete('flagging')
          ->condition('entity_type', $entity_type)
          ->condition('entity_id', $entity_id)
          ->condition('flag_id', $flag_id)
          ->condition('uid', $uid)
          ->execute();



          $response['¿Delete flag?'] = 'true';
        }
        else {

          $response['¿Flag exists?'] = 'false';

        }


        $response['data'] = $data;


    }










    /*

    //send json example
    //change "bookmark"  by "my_flag"


    {
      "entity_id":31,
      "entity_type":"node",
      "flag_id": "bookmark", 
      "uid": 1,
      "flag_action": "flag"
    }

    */



    return new JsonResponse( $response );
  }

  /**
   * Callback for `my-api/delete.json` API method.
   */
  public function delete_example( Request $request ) {

    $response['data'] = 'Some test data to return';
    $response['method'] = 'DELETE';

    return new JsonResponse( $response );
  }

}
```

Note: in the tests change "bookmark"  by "my_flag"

test: 
url: http://jeremiselxi.260mb.net/drupal8/my-api/post.json
method:post;
headers: 
Content-type: application/json
X-CSRF-Token: token()

note: this token is obtained through the GET method to the url
localhost/session/token

create flag

```
{
  "entity_id":34,
  "entity_type":"node",
  "flag_id": "bookmark", 
  "uid": 1,
  "flag_action": "flag"
}
```

result:

```
200 OK

Headers
{
  "newflag": "22",
  "data": {
    "entity_id": 34,
    "entity_type": "node",
    "flag_id": "bookmark",
    "uid": 1,
    "flag_action": "flag"
  }
}
```

note: If the flag does not exist, then create the flag

```
"newflag": "22"
```

else

```
"¿Flag exists?": "true"
```

create unflag

```
{
  "entity_id":34,
  "entity_type":"node",
  "flag_id": "bookmark", 
  "uid": 1,
  "flag_action": "unflag"
}
```

result:

```
200 OK

Headers
{
  "¿Delete flag?": "true",
  "data": {
    "entity_id": 34,
    "entity_type": "node",
    "flag_id": "bookmark",
    "uid": 1,
    "flag_action": "unflag"
  }
}
```

note: If the flag exists, then delete the flag

```
"¿Delete flag?": "true"
```

else

```
"¿Flag exists?": "false",
```

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked very well for me. This is the code that I used.

Comment: Awesome. I have tried and it worked!

Comment: Excellent .... Any concerns or doubts, I'm here

Comment: @JHONATANDAVIDFERNANDEZROSA This is stunnig. This saved me !! Thanks a lot.. I think Drupal has to fix post flagging only adminster permission.